# How to differ queries in Ruby helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

While refactoring I though it'll b great to convert

```
%p.user-greatings #{gravatar_for @project.user} #{link_to @project.user.name, @project.user}
```

to helper method in order to follow DRY convention.

My raw helper method:

```
def assigned_user
  gravatar_for yield link_to yield.name, yield
end
```

And my view:

```
%p.user-greatings #{assigned_user{@project.user}}
```

But my "assigned_user" displays only one part:

```
gravatar_for yield
```

How to change my method to display both parts in my view?

Answer (score 2):

Calling methods while not adding braces can be confusing. Actually you are calling:

```
def assigned_user
  gravatar_for(yield(link_to(yield.name, yield)))
end
```

Since your block ignores the parameters passed to it, you get something equivalent to

```
gravatar_for yield
```

I'm not sure what you tried to do, and why did you opt to bass a block rather than a simple value:

```
def assigned_user(user)
  "#{gravatar_for user} #{link_to user.name, user}"
end

%p.user-greatings #{assigned_user(@project.user)}
```

Comment: I choose yield just coz I rarely use it)
Same thing both with yield and value - when I start new line for query it displays only second value.

Comment: So in your case it displays only "link_to user.name, user"

Comment: @dimitryeurope you see only the last value, because the last value is the _return value_. I've updated my answer to concatenate both lines

Comment: <img alt="Pontifix Maximus" class="gravatar img-rounded" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/6f992b8b1cf0bac8b11a6e792cf5412c" /> <a href="/users/1">Pontifix Maximus</a>

Comment: It comes like a simle text because of " "